# Generating pdf & midi from musicxml

Tags: python, lilypond, music21, music-notation, musicxml

I've been trying to load a MusicXML file, edit it (removing several parts), and create a PDF sheet document + midi/mp3, all of this using Python.

I've first looked at `music21`, that would load my MusicXML file right, but as far as I could find, would not output a proper file (all the details in the output files have disappeared, all that's left is the notes and the title)

Then I found `abjad` which looked promising. It did output great quality ly/pdf files, but there was no musicxml imported.

Then, I discovered that Lilypond comes with a `musicxml2ly` script. I was able to call it and get the result lilypond file in python using `sh` (great lib !) but then the `abjad` `lilypond` parser would not parse it (the doc says it parses a "large subset" for lilypond, without more precisions).

Finally, I found that `music21` had an exporter to abjad python objects but it seems not to be present in the codebase anymore and the source code for the exporter clearly just exported the notes.

I'm a little out of options, what could I do to achieve these goals ?

(additional point : I still don't know how I'm going to do the second part, going to midi/mp3 using soundfonts, but that may not be the hardest part. Any suggestion ?)

Comment: Hi Joachim, did you think discussing these issues at LilyPond's mailing list, where you can contact other LilyPond users and developers? Normally that is the best (and fastest) way to solve a problem or get an answer. To sign up, please visit lilypond.org/contact.html

Comment: The music21 to Abjad converter was just a proof of concept to Abjad 1 (hacked it out w/ the Abjad creators one day) and was removed because it didn't get very far and didn't work with Abjad 2. You're right that music21's conversion to Lilypond is not particularly robust. Why not edit the MusicXML file with music21 and then write out a new MusicXML file and send that to musicxml2ly?

Answer (score 4):

If you have MuseScore 2+, you can set it up in python

```
import music21
c = music21.converter.parse('path_to_musicxml.xml')
c.show('musicxml.pdf')
c.show('midi')
```